# AttributeError at /signup

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add a signin feature to my movie project on django and this error is showing:

**AttributeError at /signin
'str' object has no attribute 'POST'**

**this is the template, signin.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
  <h1>Sign-in</h1>
  <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label class="form-label"></label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="u" placeholder="Enter your username">
    <div class="form-text"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="mb-3">
    <label class="form-label"></label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="p" placeholder="Enter your password">
    <div class="form-text"></div>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>

  {% if messages %}
  {% for i in messages%}
  <ul class='messages'>
    <li>{{i}}</li>
  </ul>
  {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

**path**

```
from django.urls import path
from movie import views
app_name='movie'
urlpatterns = [
    path('signin',views.signin,name='signin'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from django.contrib import messages

def signin(request):
    if(request.method=='POST'):
        u=request.method.POST['u']
        p=request.method.POST['p']
        user=authenticate(username=u,password=p)
        if user:
            login(request,user)
            return home(request)
        else:
            messages.error(request,'Invalid Credentials')
    return render(request,'signin.html')
```

**The error is showing after clicking submit...**

Answer (score 0):

It is not `request.method.POST`, but [**`request.POST`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST), so:

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


def signin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u = request.POST['u']
        p = request.POST['p']
        user = authenticate(username=u, password=p)
        if user:
            login(request, user)
            return home(request)
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Invalid Credentials')
    return render(request, 'signin.html')
```

---

> **Note**: Instead of implementing your own login view, you can easily customize Django's [**`LoginView`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView) with custom templates and messages. This results in less boilerplate code and makes it less vulnerable to (security) bugs.